# How to share convolution kernels between layers in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Suppose I want to compare two images with deep convolutional NN. How can I implement two different pathways with the same kernels in keras?

Like this:

[image]

I need convolutional layers 1,2 and 3 use and train the same kernels.

Is it possible?

I was also thinking to concatenate images like below

[image]

but question is about how to implement tolopology on first picture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You can use the same layer twice** in the model, creating [nodes](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#the-concept-of-layer-node):

```
from keras.models import Model    
from keras.layers import *

#create the shared layers
layer1 = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size.....)
layer2 = Conv2D(...)    
layer3 = ....

#create one input tensor for each side
input1 = Input((imageX, imageY, channels))
input2 = Input((imageX, imageY, channels))   

#use the layers in side 1
out1 = layer1(input1)   
out1 = layer2(out1)   
out1 = layer3(out1)

#use the layers in side 2
out2 = layer1(input2)   
out2 = layer2(out2)   
out2 = layer3(out2)

#concatenate and add the fully connected layers
out = Concatenate()([out1,out2])
out = Flatten()(out)
out = Dense(...)(out)   
out = Dense(...)(out)   

#create the model taking 2 inputs with one output
model = Model([input1,input2],out)
```

**You could also use the same model twice**, making it a submodel of a bigger one:

```
#have a previously prepared model 
convModel = some model previously prepared

#define two different inputs
input1 = Input((imageX, imageY, channels))
input2 = Input((imageX, imageY, channels))   

#use the model to get two different outputs:
out1 = convModel(input1)
out2 = convModel(input2)

#concatenate the outputs and add the final part of your model: 
out = Concatenate()([out1,out2])
out = Flatten()(out)
out = Dense(...)(out)   
out = Dense(...)(out)   

#create the model taking 2 inputs with one output
model = Model([input1,input2],out)
```

Comment: Are you sure it will train accordingly? Will it recognize gradients properly?

Comment: Yes, Keras has the notion of "nodes", which are created only when you pass an input tensor to a layer. When you do it more than once, the layer gets many nodes. Then, if you want the output of that layer, instead of doing `layer[i].output` you will start using `layer[i].get_output_at(node_index)`, for instance.

Comment: I just tested a little MNIST model taking two images at the same time to classificate both together using this code. It worked great :)

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. the model is built and trained nicely. but then it fails to load with an obscure exception `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv9x9: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 16 but got shape (None, 62, 62, 4)`. Anyone else seen that issue?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed using the same (instance of) layer twice ensures that the weights will be shared.

Just look at the [siamese example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_siamese_graph.py), I just put here an excerpt from the model to show an example:

```
# because we re-use the same instance `base_network`,
# the weights of the network
# will be shared across the two branches
processed_a = base_network(input_a)
processed_b = base_network(input_b)
```