# Can some use the Con2d in tensorflow or keras repeatedly with the same kernel parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I just come across a strange idea that requires me to use the same convolutional layer repeatedly. BTW I am using `tensorflow 1.13.1` and `keras 2.2.4`.

In usual case of `keras`, it just goes like,

```
x = Conv2D()(x)
x = Conv2D()(x)
...
```

But that means 2 different 2D convolutional layers are applied, and I want to use the same convolution kernels repeatedly.

I found out [`tf.contrib.layers.repeat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/repeat) which seems to answer my question.

Is there some other ways to do the same things? Or is that not worth trying at all. Thanks!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share convolution kernels between layers in keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44810826/how-to-share-convolution-kernels-between-layers-in-keras)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Keras Functional API for this:

```
layer = Conv2D(...)
input = Input(...)
x = input

x = layer(x)
x = layer(x)
```

This applies the exact same convolutional layer two times, with the same weights/kernels.