# Training a convolution network with 2 convolution operation with shared weights that must keep a norm of 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, convolution

I want to train a convolution network with 4 convolution operations with 2 filters that share weights, but with a norm that stays to 1 between the elements of the filters. Let's say I have input matrix A and B, and filter C and D. The operation I want to make is :

M1 = tf.conv2d(A,C)

M2 = tf.conv2d(B,C)

M3 = tf.conv2d(A,D)

M4 = tf.conv2d(B,D)

At the same time, I need sqrt(C^2+D^2)=1

I have found a way to share the weights between the different convolution operation by using the same layer twice, as was asked in a previous question
 [How to share convolution kernels between layers in keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44810826/how-to-share-convolution-kernels-between-layers-in-keras).

But I have no idea how to formulate the constraints of the norm to 1.

Thx!

I have tried to introduce an Input layer that would be trained via a Dense layer with the dimension of my kernel filter, and then reshape and split it into 2 using cos(x) sin(x) before the convolution operation (I'm already doing this in the code to modulate the input image). I then use a manual tf.nn.conv2d() operation. But with the kernels I get a dimension of the batch as the 0 dimension and this is incompatible with the required dimension of the kernel [filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]. Squeezing it won't work.

```py
conv2d_layer_real= Conv2D(1,data_Mat2.shape[1],padding='same',kernel_constraint=max_norm(1),use_bias =False)
conv2d_layer_imag = Conv2D(1,data_Mat2.shape[1],padding='same',kernel_constraint=max_norm(1),use_bias =False)

input_shape = (data_Mat2.shape[1], data_Mat2.shape[1],1);
input_shape2 = (1,);

inputs_r = Input(shape=input_shape)
inputs_r2 = Input(shape=input_shape2)

phase_r2 = Dense(data_Mat2.shape[1]*data_Mat2.shape[1],activation = 'tanh',use_bias =False,kernel_initializer=RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.5, seed=None))(inputs_r2)

phase_real = Lambda(lambda x:tf.cos(x*3.1416))(phase_r2)
phase_imag = Lambda(lambda x:tf.sin(x*3.1416))(phase_r2)

phase_real2 = Reshape((data_Mat2.shape[1], data_Mat2.shape[1],1))(phase_real)
phase_imag2 = Reshape((data_Mat2.shape[1], data_Mat2.shape[1],1))(phase_imag)

Mat_real = Multiply()([inputs_r,phase_real2])
Mat_imag = Multiply()([inputs_r,phase_imag2])

out_conv1 = conv2d_layer_real(Mat_real)
out_conv2 = conv2d_layer_real(Mat_imag)

out_conv3 = conv2d_layer_imag(Mat_real)
out_conv4 = conv2d_layer_imag(Mat_imag)

out_real = Add()([out_conv1,-out_conv4])
out_imag = Add()([out_conv2,out_conv3])

image_out = tf.complex(out_real,out_imag)
image_out = tf.square(tf.abs(image_out))

image_out = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(pool_s, pool_s))(image_out)

vector_out = Reshape((9,))(image_out)

outputs = Softmax()(vector_out)
```

This last code works well but won't have a norm of 1 for the weigths of the conv2D layers because no such constraints is made